# Html Webpack Plugin: error while generating cra ts project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am trying to generate a react project with `npx create-react-app app-name --template typescript` but after generating when I run `npm start` It shows a big chunk of error and I've tried several times, and still not working and I can't figure out what's going on with the issue.

And it also pops out now when I am trying to clone another project from git and running `npm i` and `npm start` I am getting the same error in the console and in the browser.

Here is the error:

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed (from ../../#work/vh/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
  Error: Cannot find module 'H:\#work\vh\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
  Require stack:
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
      at loadLoader (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:19:17)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
      at runLoaders (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:814:3)
      at NormalModule.build (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:958:15)
      at H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1369:12
  ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ../../#work/vh/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
  Error: Cannot find module 'H:\#work\vh\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
  Require stack:
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
  - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
      at loadLoader (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:19:17)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
      at runLoaders (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:814:3)
      at NormalModule.build (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:958:15)
      at H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1369:12
      at processResult (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:753:19)
      at H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:855:5
      at H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
      at H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:185:11
      at loadLoader (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:33:11)
      at iteratePitchingLoaders (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:2)
      at runLoaders (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
      at NormalModule._doBuild (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:814:3)
      at NormalModule.build (H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:958:15)
      at H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1369:12
  
  - loader:933 Function.Module._resolveFilename
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15
  
  - loader:778 Function.Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27
  
  - loader:1005 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19
  
  - helpers:102 require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18
  
  - loadLoader.js:19 loadLoader
    [vh]/[loader-runner]/lib/loadLoader.js:19:17
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:182 iteratePitchingLoaders
    [vh]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:182:2
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:397 runLoaders
    [vh]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:397:2
  
  - NormalModule.js:814 NormalModule._doBuild
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:814:3
  
  - NormalModule.js:958 NormalModule.build
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:958:15
  
  - Compilation.js:1369 
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1369:12
  
  - ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ../../#work/vh/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
  
  - Error: Cannot find module 'H:\#work\vh\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\loader.js'
  
  - Require stack:
  
  - - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
  
  - - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
  
  - - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
  
  - - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
  
  - - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
  
  - - H:\#work\vh\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
  
  - loader:933 Function.Module._resolveFilename
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15
  
  - loader:778 Function.Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27
  
  - loader:1005 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19
  
  - helpers:102 require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18
  
  - loadLoader.js:19 loadLoader
    [vh]/[loader-runner]/lib/loadLoader.js:19:17
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:182 iteratePitchingLoaders
    [vh]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:182:2
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:397 runLoaders
    [vh]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:397:2
  
  - NormalModule.js:814 NormalModule._doBuild
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:814:3
  
  - NormalModule.js:958 NormalModule.build
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:958:15
  
  - Compilation.js:1369 
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1369:12
  
  - NormalModule.js:753 processResult
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:753:19
  
  - NormalModule.js:855 
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:855:5
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:399 
    [vh]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:185 
    [vh]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:185:11
  
  - loadLoader.js:33 loadLoader
    [vh]/[loader-runner]/lib/loadLoader.js:33:11
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:182 iteratePitchingLoaders
    [vh]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:182:2
  
  - LoaderRunner.js:397 runLoaders
    [vh]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:397:2
  
  - NormalModule.js:814 NormalModule._doBuild
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:814:3
  
  - NormalModule.js:958 NormalModule.build
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:958:15
  
  - Compilation.js:1369 
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1369:12
  
  - child-compiler.js:169 
    [vh]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:169:18
  
  - Compiler.js:564 
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:564:11
  
  - Compiler.js:1183 
    [vh]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1183:17
  
  
  - task_queues:96 processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5
  
  - task_queues:65 runNextTicks
    node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3
  
  - timers:437 processImmediate
    node:internal/timers:437:9
```

node -v :

`v16.13.2`

npm -v:

`8.4.1`

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "vh",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.22",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.68.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json please ?

Comment: Just added it in the post.

Comment: If you configured the project with CRA, then you don't need to install webpack plugins manually in devDependencies, those libraries comes with react-scripts itself.

Remove all the packages of devdependencies, remove node_modules
Then run npm install or yarn install again and try again

Comment: I am still getting the same issue.